# Login not working after adding HTTP Interceptor - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-http-interceptors

I have recently started working on a project someone else started, and I decided to implement HTTP Interceptor, but after I did it, I cannot log in anymore, like I am writing wrong username/pass (and I am not), but while I was logged in, everything worked fine. This is my code -

Interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
            }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Login:

```
// in http service
public postAuth(url: string,  body?: object): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + url, body)
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => new ErrorObservable(error))
    );
  }
// in auth service
login(email: string, password: string): void {
    const body = {username: email, password: password};

    this._http.postAuth('/auth/waplogin/', body)
    .map(res => {
      return {
        token: res.token,
        firstName: res.user.first_name,
        lastName: res.user.last_name,
        id: res.user.uuid
      }
    })
    .subscribe(
      loggedUserInfoToken => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('loggedUserInfoToken', JSON.stringify(loggedUserInfoToken));
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      },
      err => {
        this.loginErr = err.statusText;
        this.checkError(this.loginErr);
      }
    );
  }
```

Not sure if it is linked, but this is when it stopped working, no errors in console though.

EDIT: Done it, just changed this part:

```
if (this.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Token ${this.auth.getToken()}`
                }
            });
        }
```

didn't see this method existed in the code..

Comment: which version are you using RXJS?

Comment: @KrishnaRathore huh, how to check that?

Comment: go to package.json and you will find rxjs there

Comment: @KrishnaRathore ^5.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `this.auth.getToken()` is fetching stored token from `sessionStorage`. If that is not the case then make sure that token is retrieved properly.

Also, you can try ignoring the authentication request in the interceptor

```
//Check for url. If it is login url then return    
if (request.url.includes('/auth/waplogin/')) {
   return next.handle(request);
}
```

Updated Interceptor should be like this -

```
    @Injectable()
    export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            //Check for url. If it is login url then return    
            if (request.url.includes('/auth/waplogin/')) {
               return next.handle(request);
            }
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
                }
            });
            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can I do that, ignore the authentication? That is the problem, I am trying to fetch a token that does not exist yet. I tried with if (this.auth.getToken()) { ... set headers here ... }

Comment: I have updated the answer. Update your interceptor code as suggested. Basically, you check url of every request intercepted. If the Url is for authentication request, then you just return and don't set the header.

Comment: this.auth.getToken(); Where do u set token and where is it stored?

Answer (score 2):

In `app.module.ts` add :

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: TokenInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },
    ]
```

http-intercepter.ts:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param req - parameter to handle http request
 * @param next - parameter for http handler
 */
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const started = Date.now();
    /**
     * Handle newly created request with updated header (if given)
     */
    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        /**
         * Sucessfull Http Response Time.
         */
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            const elapsed = Date.now() - started;
        }

    }, (err: any) => {
        /**
         * redirect to the error_handler route according to error status or error_code
         * or show a modal
         */
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            switch (err.status) {

            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: use next.handle(req).do()

Comment: return {
        token: res.token,
        firstName: res.user.first_name,
        lastName: res.user.last_name,
        id: res.user.uuid
      }  what is that??

Comment: That is what is inside the sessionStorage, like a model (found this code, not done by me)

Comment: try to remove 'return' and let me know.

Comment: You mean I should use your structure, and add my code inside if statement?

Comment: due to 'return' statement  subscription is being ignored.